# how to delete from database row selected with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql

I have the following codes:

file lecturer.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $(".use-address").click(function() {
             var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
             var names = $row.find(".name").text(); // Find the name
             var surname = $row.find(".surname").text(); // Find the surname                

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_lecturer.php",
                    data:{ x: names, y: surname}
                });

             });

        });
```

file delete_lecturer.php:

```
<?php

ob_start(); //eliminates buffer collisions
    require_once('connect_db.php'); 
    if (!empty($_POST['x'])){   $name = $_POST['x']; }
    if (!empty($_POST['y'])){   $surname = $_POST['y']; }
    $result = pg_query(connect(), "delete from lecturer where name='$name' and surname='$surname'");    
    echo "did it";
    //dump the result object
    var_dump($result);
    // Closing connection

    //reloading the page
    header("location: lecturer.php?fail=2");
?>
```

The file connect_db.php works (I have tested it with other files requiring it). I am trying to get a name and surname from a table, pass it to the delete_lecturer.php file and delete the rows that match my selection from the database. The name and surname in the jquery code are stored correctly (i have tested that too).

But the code still doesn't work.
Any ideas what's wrong or how to fix it?
 By the way, im using postgresql for the database.

Comment: Is your console, showing you some kind of error after you execute that function?
Or write a code like success(msg) and fail(msg) after the ajax execution, dont do "header"

Comment: I will try your suggestion, thanks. But for now it wont show any errors.

Comment: You can try too, before send the data "names" and "surname" do a console.log() on those 2 variables, to check if they contain something in

Comment: I removed the header line and echoed $name. Nothing happens. Also added alert(names+surname); after getting the data in jquery. They are printed correctly in the alert box.

Comment: You are subject to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) use `pg_query_params()` instead -- redirecting (`Location` header) an ajax call does not make too much sense to me -- are you sure jquery send your ajax request urlencoded (not as a json string)?

Comment: I removed other code in my post (like against sql injection) for the sake of simplicity. Also, removed the redirection. -- pardon my ignorance, i am using jquery for the first time and am not sure what you are suggesting in the last sentence.

Comment: @amygrimaldi one can set up jQuery to send ajax requests as json (`application/json`) -- f.ex. your query's body would look like `{"x":"<names>","y":"<surname>"}` if it's sent as json, and it would look like `x=<names>&y=<surname>` if it's sent as urlencoded (only the latter form will be processed automatically in PHP into `$_POST`). you can debug it in almost every browser's console -- net tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this code:

```
           $.ajax({  type: "POST",  
                url: "delete_lecturer.php",
                data: { x: names, y: surname}
            })

            .done(function( msg ) {
                msg = $.trim(msg);
                // Use alert or console.log()
                alert(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            })
            .fail(function( msg ) {
                // Use alert or console.log()
                alert(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            });
```

Using that code, you can check where is your code wrong, since it doesn't seems to be any problem

Comment: i havent solved the problem yet, but it seems to be a foreign key issue. Ill deal with it. Thanks for the advise. I cant rate answers yet - but yours might have just saved me.

Comment: Ok, as soon as you can please rate my answer if helped you to closed this question, and comment if you want at the end to know how you fixed your problem

Comment: Sure I will. For the moment, since the rows i was deleting contained a key referenced in two other tables, it wouldn't let me delete it using that query. The log you suggested indicated me that. I hadn't really thought about it.

Comment: If you can't rate the answer, at least you can mark it as complete; click the "check button" under down arrow